# Try and except python code

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I am trying to search for a number in a file. If the number is in the file it will display the row. however, if it's not i want it to say **product not found**. I have tried the following code which works, but product not found isn't displaying.

```
def find_item():
    product=input("Enter your product number here: ")
    search=open("products.txt")

    try:
        for x in search:
            if product in x:
                print(x)   
    except:
        print("product not found")


find_item()
```

Comment: Your `product not found` will only be displayed if the statements under try produces some error

Comment: Thanks dnit13. When i enter a correct product number it will display the details from the list. When I put an incorrect code in the 'product not found' doesn't print. The program just ends

Comment: yes because that print statement will never be executed unless you get some exception in try

Answer (score 0):

The code under `try` doesn't produce any exception if the product is not found. This task would be much easier to accomplish with a flag variable:

```
found = False
for x in search:
    if product in x:
        print(x)
        found = True
        # possibly also break here if the product can only appear once

if not found:
    print("product not found")
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much Mureinik